# Database servers, partitions and instances

Tags: mysql, postgresql, partitioning, sharding

In MySQL (and PostgreSQL), what exactly constitutes a DB instance and a DB partition?

For example, do different **DB partitions** need to necessarily live on different **database instances**?  Or can a single DB instance manage multiple partitions? If the latter, what's the point of calling it a **"partition"**? Would the DB have any knowledge of it in this case?

Here's a quote from a document describing a system design from an online course:

> **How can we plan for the future growth of our system?**
>
> We can have a large number of logical partitions to accommodate future data growth, such that in the beginning, **multiple logical partitions** reside on a single **physical database server**. Since **each database server** can have **multiple database instances** on it, we can have separate databases for each logical partition on any server. So whenever we feel that a particular database server has a lot of data, we can migrate some logical partitions from it to another server. We can maintain a config file (or a separate database) that can map our logical partitions to database servers; this will enable us to move partitions around easily. Whenever we want to move a partition, we only have to update the config file to announce the change.

Comment: Be specific - which database system? I think that text is talking about sharding, not partitions.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I am primarily interested in MySQL, but left it open to PostgreSQL since it sounds like these concepts may be relatively universal

Comment: Can you provide a link to the quoted material? I am guessing that that is not from the official docs of either mysql or postgresql.

Comment: Looks like it is from https://quizlet.com/444358211/designing-instagram-flash-cards/

Comment: _Sharding_ involves multiple instances.  In MySQL, _Partitioning_ should be limited to a single instance.  See my answers.

Comment: Your homework answer should focus on how to shard, how to maintain the dictionary or hash lookup, how to migrate what they call a "partition", and how to avoid to mitigate downtime when you do have to move between shards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These terms are confusing, misused, and inconsistently defined.

**For MySQL:**

A **Database** has multiple definitions:

- A "schema" (as used by other vendors/standards).  This is a collection of tables.  There are one or more "databases in an instance.
- The instance.  You should use "server" or "database server" to be clearer.
- The data.  "Dataset" might be a better term.

An **instance** refers to a copy of `mysqld` running on some machine somewhere.

- You can have multiple instances on a single piece of hardware.  (Rare)
- You can have multiple instances on a single piece of hardware, with the instances in different VMs or Dockers.  (handy for testing)
- Usually "instance" refers to one server with one copy of MySQL on it.  (Typical for larger-scale situations)

A **`PARTITION`** is a specific way to lay out a `table` (in a `database`).

- It is seen in `CREATE TABLE (...) PARTITION BY ...`.
- It is a "horizontal" split of the data, often by date, but could be by some other 'column'.
- It have no direct impact on performance, making it rarely useful.

**Sharding** is not implemented in MySQL, but can be done on top of MySQL.

- It is also a "horizontal" split of the data, but in this case across multiple "instances".
- The use case is, for example, social media where there are millions of "users" that are mostly handled by themselves.  That is, most of the queries focus on a single slice of the data, hence it is practical to a bunch of users on one server and do all those queries there.
- It can be called "horizontal partitioning" but should not be confused with `PARTITIONs` of a table.

**Vertical partitioning** is where some *columns* are pulled out of a table in put into a parallel table.

- Both tables would (normally) have the same `PRIMARY KEY`, thereby facilitating `JOINs`.
- Vertical partitioning would (normally) be done only in a single "instance".
- The purposes include splitting off big text/blog columns; splitting off optional columns (and use `LEFT JOIN` to get `NULLs`).
- Vertical partitioning was somewhat useful in MyISAM, but rarely useful in InnoDB, since that engine automatically does such.

**Replication** and **Clustering**

- Multiple instances contain the same data.
- Used for "High Availability" (HA).
- Used for scaling out reads.
- Orthogonally to partitioning or sharding.
- Does not make sense to have the instances on the same server (except for testing/experimenting/staging/etc).

Answer (score 2):

Partitions, in terms of MySQL and PostgreSQL feature set, are physical segmentations of data.  They exist within a single database instance, and are used to reduce the scope of data you're interacting with at a particular time, to cope with high data volume situations.

The document you're quoting from is speaking of a more abstract concept of a data partition at the system design level.

Comment: Thanks @chaos so it's correct to say that (at least in MySQL and PostgreSQL), a server can contain a number of instances, and an instance can contain a number of partitions (for a given set of tables), but we can't have instances share partitions, or servers share instances, right?

Comment: Correct as far as the kind MySQL/PostgreSQL kind of partitioning goes.  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_(database_architecture)